# Context menu remains visible during command execution

Tags: wpf

I have a long running command that is started via a context menu. The context menu remains open till the command execution ends. I find this awkward. Tow questions:

- Is that the way Windows programs should behave?
- Is there a way to close the menu before the command is executed?

The application is MVVM and I would not like to program against the UI directly. Below is a simple code showing the behavior.

Please note: In the real application a wait cursor is displayed during command execution. Also, I do not want to run the command execution in a background thread but rather have the user wait till the command is finished.

XAML:

```
Window x:Class="WpfApp4__Various_Tests_.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4__Various_Tests_"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    x:Name="root">

<Grid>
    <Rectangle 
        Fill="ForestGreen"
        Height="100" Width="200" Margin="10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        >
        <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem
                    Header="Long running ommand"
                    Click="MenuItem_Click"
                    />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Rectangle.ContextMenu>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu can't be closed because you block the UI thread with the handler. To fix the example you show here, use this:

```cs
private async void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));
}
```

In your actual program, you may or may not be calling code that is inherently async. If it is, you can do the same as above and `await` the result. If not, you should wrap the code in an async-friendly task. At the bare minimum, that would look something like this:

```cs
private async void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(3000));
}
```

And I do mean **bare minimum**. Without knowing more about your long-running task, it's impossible to give anything more specific in the way of advice. However, a couple of important points:

- The long-running task may require periodic interaction with objects owned by the UI thread. If you are strictly using data binding, WPF will automatically handle cross-thread notifications that occur via `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Notifications from `INotifyCollectionChanged` (e.g. `ObserveableCollection<T>`) aren't handled by default, but you can enabled that with [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization).
- It is also very helpful if you can recompose your long-running task as sequences of awaitable, non-UI-interacting operations interleaved with the UI-interacting stuff. Then you can just use `async`/`await` to manage the cross-thread aspects. This approach is particularly important if you aren't using data binding (but if you aren't, you should be!).

Comment: Thank you Peter. Do so (await Task.Run...) is a solution, however I need to take care when accessing collections bound to a datagrid. I was therefore thinking of calling "await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));" before starting the operation to get rid of the context menu. 
What do you think of that?

Comment: I'm not fond of it myself. As a general rule, solutions taking the form of "insert arbitrary delay in the code" are something I try very hard to avoid. In this case, if you do nothing more than that, the UI still will freeze for the duration. The menu may go away, but the rest of the UI will still be unresponsive. If you set the `EnabledCollectionSychronization` property, then your bound collection should still work properly. Alternatively, populate the data in the background and only copy it to the bound collection when done.